# MySQL Unknown Column Error 1054 Simple Update

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Using MySQL workbench, I'm getting odd behavior when attempting to execute the following statement:

```
UPDATE Jobs SET Customer = 'Ben' WHERE PO = 1011;
```

The output of which is: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Jobs.PO' in 'where clause'

The goal here is to get the update statement, or equivalent, to execute.  I can't determine the issue.  What's particularly odd is that the following statements:

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs;
SELECT PO FROM Jobs;
SELECT * FROM Jobs where PO = 1011;
SELECT PO FROM Jobs where PO = 1011;
```

all function exactly as expected.  Specifically, no errors, returns and displays all entries asked for. Why might a select execute without a 1054 error when the update can't?

The create table statement (if it's helpful), executed as a SQL script through workbench:

```
CREATE TABLE `Jobs` (
    PO MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    Part TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `Last Dash` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    Customer VARCHAR(80),
    Description VARCHAR(350),
    Completed DATE,
    Notes VARCHAR(350),
    CONSTRAINT pkJobs PRIMARY KEY (PO, Part)
);
```

EDIT::
Perhaps not as simple as I originally construed.  There exists a 'before update' trigger on the table.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS JobsUp //
CREATE TRIGGER JobsUp BEFORE UPDATE ON Jobs FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF new.`Last Dash` < (SELECT MAX(Dash) 
        FROM Tracking AS t 
        WHERE new.PO = t.PO 
        AND new.Part = t.Part 
    ) THEN 

        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 
            'Cannot update last dash to value less than an assigned dash.'; 

    END IF;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I cannot recreate your error using the schema provided with the update query.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The database was operating from a previous definition of the JobsUp trigger which did not utilize the 'new' keyword.  Recreating the trigger solved the issue.